# GIven a surface area F, a normal vector, a point and a vector field, calculate the flow of the vector field through F.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

the surface F, the vector field v, the point P and the normal vector n are defined as follows:

$$ F = \vec{x}(s,t) = \begin{bmatrix}s \\t \\s^2+t^2 \end{bmatrix} \ s,t \in [0,1]$$
$$\vec{n} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} in \ point \ P = \ (0,0,0)$$
$$\vec{v}(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix} xy^2 \\ x^2y \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

a) Calculate the flow $\int\int_F \vec{v}dF$ of the vector field $\vec{v}$ through $F$.

My solution attempt using the divergence theorem:

$\int_C<\vec{v},\vec{n}>ds = \int\int_\Sigma div\ \vec{v}\ dA$ with $div\ \vec{v} = y^2+x^2$
$\rightarrow \int_0^1\int_0^1x^2+y^2dydx=\frac{2}{3}$

c) Calculate the integral of the vector field $v$ along the boundary $\partial F$ of $F$.

My solution attempt using Stokes' theorem:

$\int_{\partial F}\vec{v} \ dx = \int\int_\Sigma<curl \ \vec{v}, \vec{n}>dA$ and since $curl \ \vec{v} = 0$ the integral is also equal to zero.

Parts of the solution where I am unsure: Is the surface F closed? How can one quickly check this? If it isn't closed, I cannot apply the divergence theorem and hence have to calculate the given integral. How would I do this? Why do they give me the parametrization of F, and why do they give me the normal vector only in the point P?

Comment: Q. "Is the surface F closed? How can one quickly check this?" A. Draw a picture. Or use https://www.geogebra.org/m/pwrefcyf .

Comment: Q. "If it isn't closed, I cannot apply the divergence theorem and hence have to calculate the given integral. How would I do this?" A. Dot $\vec{v}$ with the normal vector to the surface and integrate that over the surface.

Comment: Q. "Why do they give me the parametrization of F, and why do they give me the normal vector only in the point P?" A. To orient the normal vectors at the surface.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks, but is there another way than to draw a picture? First of all I don't really have a good intuition with these things and I also think that sometimes the surfaces/solids can get a bit funky.. I know that F represents a paraboloid with the opening towards the positive z-axis. But if this is not closed, how can a surface be closed then? would it have to be flat?

Comment: No one said that the surface is closed. You need to find ways to figure this out. I suggested two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an approach for part a). We compute the flow $\phi$ through surface $F$. The flow $d \phi$ through a particular surface element $dS$ is $d \phi = \textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{n} dS$. We are given parameters for $F$:

$$ \textbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}x \\y \\z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}s \\t \\s^2+t^2 \end{bmatrix} $$

as well as a flow field $\textbf{v}$:

$$ \textbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix}xy^2 \\x^2y \\1 \end{bmatrix} $$

which at the surface $F$ is equal to:

$$ \textbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix}st^2 \\s^2t \\1 \end{bmatrix} $$

From the parameters we can compute the differential surface element $dS$:

$$ dS = \lvert \textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t \rvert dsdt $$

where:

$$\textbf{r}_s = \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} \textbf{i} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \textbf{j} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} \textbf{k}$$

$$= 1 \textbf{i} + 0 \textbf{j} + 2s \textbf{k}$$

and similarly for $\textbf{r}_t$ we get $0 \textbf{i} + 1 \textbf{j} + 2t \textbf{k}$. Therefore the cross product $\textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t$ is:

$$ \textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t = -2s \textbf{i} - 2t \textbf{j} + 1 \textbf{k} $$

Now the flow through $F$ is obtained from integrating the flow through each surface element:

$$ \phi = \int d \phi = \int \textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{n} \lvert \textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t \rvert dsdt $$

The normal vector $\textbf{n}$ is related to $\textbf{r}_s$ and $\textbf{r}_t$ as follows:

$$ \textbf{n} = -\frac{\textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t }{\lvert \textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t \rvert} $$

which coincides with the given normal vector at $s,t = 0$. And so:

$$ \phi = \int_S \textbf{v} \cdot (-1)\frac{\textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t }{\lvert \textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t \rvert} \lvert \textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t \rvert dsdt = -\int_S (\textbf{r}_s \times \textbf{r}_t) \cdot \textbf{v} dsdt $$

$$ = \int_S \begin{bmatrix}2s \\2t \\-1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}st^2 \\s^2 t \\1 \end{bmatrix} dsdt $$

Which means:

$$ \phi = \int_S 4s^2 t^2 - 1 ds dt $$

$$ = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 4s^2 t^2 - 1 ds dt = -\frac{5}{9}$$

Comment: Almost too good. It seems to me that the orientation of $\mathbf{r}_s\times \mathbf{r}_t$ should be flipped given OP's $\vec{\mathbf{n}}$ at $(0,0,0)\,.$

Comment: Indeed, good one. I've edited the answer.